# i am getting this error while i tried to use sqllite with flutter its not creating the tble pls any solutions?

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, dart, backend

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Future<Database> database() async {
    final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'places.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE user_places(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, image TEXT)');
    }, version: 1);
  }

  static Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, Object> data) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    db.insert(
      table,
      data,
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData(String table) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    return db.query(table);
  }
}
```

this is the code where I tried implementing it but its giving the error like below
=>no such table: places in "SELECT * FROM places"

Comment: Are you sure this table name exists?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your table is named `user_places`, so the error message is correct.

Whether you want it to be called "places" or "user_places" is up to you, but you need to pick one.